# Just started with raspberry pi. Any help about where to start?

Tags: pi-3

I just got two Raspberry pi's working today, (I installed raspian), and I really don't know where to learn. I bought a few books, but they only suggest projects, and not how to use the pi. Any help?

Comment: Try reading https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/beginners-guide/

Comment: For most practical purposes a Raspberry running Raspbian is like any other computer running Linux so you can use most Linux tutorials (or Unix for the command line things).  What would you like to do on it?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Note that your question is quite broad and likely very subjective to answer. No one but you can tell what it is you want to do, thus is is hard to give a good answer. The MagPi, as already pointed out, is a good way to start, but so are books with "projects". Start out with simple projects and learn as you go.